# ‘controlled_runge_kutta’ is not a class template

Tags: c++, templates, boost, odeint

It is a known error in the following code:

> ‘controlled_runge_kutta’ is not a class template

In the following code:

```
template<
class ErrorStepper ,
class ErrorChecker ,
class Resizer
>
class controlled_runge_kutta< ErrorStepper , ErrorChecker , Resizer , explicit_error_stepper_tag >
{
public:
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I know why I get this error. But my question is that how does it work in the original boost library from [github](https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2/blob/master/include/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/controlled_runge_kutta.hpp) in line 146?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at line 109.

```
template<
class ErrorStepper ,
class ErrorChecker = default_error_checker< typename ErrorStepper::value_type ,
typename ErrorStepper::algebra_type ,
typename ErrorStepper::operations_type > ,
class Resizer = typename ErrorStepper::resizer_type ,
class ErrorStepperCategory = typename ErrorStepper::stepper_category
>
class controlled_runge_kutta;
```

Now, there is declaration of template class, in line 146 there is just partial specialization of this class.

Answer (score 0):

If the syntax is:

```
template <template-parameters...> class NAME { ... };
```

then it's a "master template definition". If it is:

```
template <template-parameters...> class NAME<parameter-spec> { ... };
```

then it's a partial template specialization (a secondary definition that defines "mapping" for a special case of parameters.

You cannot declare a partial template specialization, if the master template definition for that name (of a class or function template) hasn't been provided yet.

So, depends on what you wanted to declare. If just a template - then remove everything that's in <...> after the class name. If a specialization, then please define the template itself first.

The `template<...>` statement doesn't mean the same in the master definition and in the specialization. In the master definition it defines the "signature" (how the "instantiation" should be invoked), in the specialization it means nothing but providing some names used inside.